# NVIDIA Start Xorg Without Monitors

Tags: xorg, headless, xorg.conf

I'm running Redhat 6.4

```
uname -ra
Linux host.domain 2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jan 29 11:47:41 EST 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The graphics card is an NVIDA Tesla C2075, Driver Version: 319.37

**Here's the problem I'm trying to solve:**

I'd like to be able to boot my server with no monitor attached. At a later time, if I plug monitors in I'd like to be able to see the graphical display.

**Current Behaviour:**

Xorg terminates because it doesn't detect any monitors. I am unable to get anything at all on the screen.

Xorg.0.log:

```
X.Org X Server 1.13.0
Release Date: 2012-09-05
[    31.569] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
...
[    34.279] (EE) Screen(s) found, but none have a usable configuration.
[    34.279]
Fatal server error:
[    34.279] no screens found
[    34.280] (EE)
Please consult the Red Hat, Inc. support
     at https://www.redhat.com/apps/support/
 for help.
[    34.280] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[    34.280] (EE)
[    34.284] Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

I tried following the steps I found here: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/54937 with limited success. I'm now able to get the console up on the screen by pressing ctrl+alt+f2 (I couldn't before), but Xorg is still terminating in the same way.

xorg.conf

```
  1 # nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
  2 # nvidia-xconfig:  version 319.37  (buildmeister@swio-display-x64-rhel04-11)  Wed Jul  3 18:14:07 PDT 2013
  3 
  4 Section "ServerLayout"
  5     Identifier     "Layout0"
  6     Screen      0  "Screen0"
  7     InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
  8     InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
  9 EndSection
 10 
 11 Section "Files"
 12 EndSection
 13 
 14 Section "InputDevice"
 15     # generated from default
 16     Identifier     "Mouse0"
 17     Driver         "mouse"
 18     Option         "Protocol" "auto"
 19     Option         "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
 20     Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
 21     Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
 22 EndSection
 23 
 24 Section "InputDevice"
 25     # generated from data in "/etc/sysconfig/keyboard"
 26     Identifier     "Keyboard0"
 27     Driver         "kbd"
 28     Option         "XkbLayout" "us"
 29     Option         "XkbModel" "pc105"
 30 EndSection
 31 
 32 Section "Device"
 33     Identifier     "Device0"
 34     Driver         "nvidia"
 35     VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
 36     Option         "ConnectedMonitor"    "DFP-0"
 37     Option         "CustomEDID" "DFP-0:/etc/X11/edid1.conf"
 38 EndSection
 39 
 40 Section "Monitor"
 41     Identifier     "Monitor0"
 42     VendorName     "Unknown"
 43     ModelName      "Unknown"
 44     HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
 45     VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
 46     Option         "DPMS"
 47 EndSection
 48 
 49 
 50 Section "Screen"
 51     Identifier     "Screen0"
 52     Device         "Device0"
 53     Monitor        "Monitor0"
 54     DefaultDepth    24
 55     SubSection     "Display"
 56         Depth       24
 57         Modes       "1920x1200"
 58     EndSubSection
 59 EndSection
```

I appreciate any help or advice anyone can give. I've hit the wall and I'm not sure how to proceed.

Thanks,

Mike

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I tried the same solution (https://access.redhat.com/solutions/54937) with a different video card and monitor and found that it worked.

Comment: hmm, I tried that link and it didn't work.